# InnoDB Storage Engine Dropped From Oracle MySQL Classic Edition?

Tags: sql, mysql, oracle, innodb

InnoDB Storage Engine Dropped From Oracle MySQL Classic Edition? What does this mean for the average developer who uses mysql or shall we start looking for alternatives?

http://digitizor.com/2010/11/05/innodb-dropped-from-oracle-mysql-classic-edition/

Thanks in advance ;-)

Just trying to understand what this really means?

Comment: How, and if so to what extent, is this related to actual programming? Even if this is a real change, it seems to relate to marketing, not coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People that you refer to use [Community Edition](http://www.mysql.com/products/community/). And nothing is changing about it.

About [Classic Edition](https://www.mysql.com/products/classic/):

> MySQL Classic Edition is only available to ISVs, OEMs and VARs to license as an embedded database.

I doubt that you used it.

Answer (score 1):

Classic Edition is a build of MySQL that is embeddable into applications, rather than a stand-alone server application.  It has never included the InnoDB storage engine.

Community Edition is the version of MySQL I would assume most people care about/are using/it's the open source version.  It still includes InnoDB.

Answer (score 0):

The classic addition is listed as appropriate for embedded applications, and it's meant to be as small as possible.  The cost listed there is if you want the support subscription, and they do not offer support for the classic edition.